# Issues with MySQL on Yosemitie

Tags: mysql, django, macos, mysql-python

I've pulled down a new Django repository that uses MySQL and after installing it I'm getting some weird errors when I go to run the syncdb command

I initially get the following error

```
  raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
  django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/splashlin/Developer/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/splashlin/Developer/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I've tried fixing it with

```
 sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
```

but just get

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: can't open file: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so (No such file or directory)
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to move forward to resolve the issue?  Pretty stuck right now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to download and install (or reinstall) the MySql's connector for Python

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

Greetings